# Calculating population size from raster layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, analysis

Is it possible (using QGIS) to calculate the population size from a raster layer within a certain area?

For example:

I have a population density raster layer (100x100 grid cell) for South Africa, and I want to determine what the population of a certain district is.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [Raster zonal statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#raster-zonal-statistics)  tool. You must create a new vector layer with polygons representing your area. Use your raster and vector data as inputs to this tool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is this plugin available with QGIS 3? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @JohnGIS I use QGIS 3.2. This is a tool, not a plugin. If you use QGIS 2.18 you can try this plugin: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html

Comment: In 3.0 you'll find it within the processing toolbox